# How to access the ArrayList of another class

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and need to figure out how to access the ArrayList from another class.

I have three classes: `Market`, `StockEntry` and `Print`

I called the print method of Print class from Market and Print class get reference of arrayList from StockEntry Class but it doesn't print anything. See below:

**Market Class**

```
public class Market {
    StockEntry stock;
    Print print;

    Market() {
        stock = new StockEntry();
        print = new Print();
    }

    void addStock (String itemName,String name, int quantity, int price) {
        stock.addStockOfItems(itemName, name, quantity, price); 
    }

    void print() {
        print.pr();
    }
}
```

**StockEntry Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StockEntry {
    Fruit fruit;
    ArrayList<Fruit> fruitList ;

    StockEntry() {
        fruit = new Fruit();
        fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    }

    void addStockOfItems(String itemName,String name, int quantity, int price) {
        fruit.enterTheDetail(name, quantity, price);
        fruitList.add(fruit);
    }
}
```

**Print Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Print {
    StockEntry stock;
    ArrayList<Fruit> fruitList;

    Print() {
        fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    }

    void pr() {
        for (Fruit fruit : stock.fruitList) {
            System.out.println(fruit);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your Print class will need a valid reference to the StockEntry object, perhaps passed into Print's constructor, and this will allow it to call methods on the StockEntry, including methods to allow it to get information on the data it holds. What you should not do is create a new StockEntry object inside of Print since if you do, it will not hold the data added to the other StockEntry used in your main class.

Note that your addStockOfItems method is broken:

```
void addStockOfItems(String itemName,String name, int quantity, int price) {
        fruit.enterTheDetail(name, quantity, price);
        fruitList.add(fruit);
}
```

You will want to create a new Fruit instance inside of this method and not change a single existing Fruit instance. Otherwise the ArrayList will contain multiple references to the one single Fruit instance.

---

For example:

**SimpleMarket.java**

```
// imports

public class SimpleMarket {
   private SimpleStockEntry stockEntry;
   private SimplePrint print;

   public SimpleMarket() {
      stockEntry = new SimpleStockEntry();
      print = new SimplePrint(stockEntry);
   }

   public void addData(String datum) {
      stockEntry.addStock(datum);
   }

   public void print() {
      print.print();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SimpleMarket market = new SimpleMarket();
      market.addData("Fe");
      market.addData("Fi");
      market.addData("Fo");
      market.addData("Fum");
      market.print();
   }
}
```

**SimpleStockEntry.java**

```
public class SimpleStockEntry {
   private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addStock(String datum) {
      myList.add(datum);
   }

   public List<String> getMyList() {
      return myList;
   }
}
```

**SimplePrint.java**

```
class SimplePrint {
   private SimpleStockEntry stockEntry;

   public SimplePrint(SimpleStockEntry stockEntry) {
      this.stockEntry = stockEntry;
   }


   public void print() {
      for (String item : stockEntry.getMyList()) {
         System.out.println(item);
      }
   }

}
```

Note that my code is not a direct answer for your assignment but rather a simplification to show you the concept of what *you* will need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the fruitlist you should have valid reference. So you probably could expose a getter method on StockEntry class and in your Market class while calling print method pass the reference you have i.e. StockEntry like below and then from stockEntry in print method get all the fruits and iterate over them

```
public class Market
{   

 StockEntry stock ;

 Print print;

Market()
{
    stock = new StockEntry();

    print = new Print();
}


void addStock (String itemName,String name, int quantity, int price)
{
    stock.addStockOfItems(itemName, name,  quantity,  price); 


 }

 void print()
 {


   print.pr(stock);

 }


}
```

Second Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StockEntry
{
  Fruit fruit ;

  ArrayList<Fruit> fruitList ;

  StockEntry()
  {

     fruit = new Fruit();

     fruitList   =  new ArrayList<Fruit>();


   }

  public ArrayList<Fruit> getFruitList() {
    return fruitList;
  }

  void addStockOfItems(String itemName,String name, int quantity, int price)
  {


      fruit.enterTheDetail(name, quantity, price);

      fruitList.add(fruit);



   }
```

Third Class

```
public class Print
{   



  void pr(StockEntry stock){

      for(Fruit fruit : stock.getFruitList()){

      System.out.println(fruit);

   }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The First thing to know is that when your println an Object, actually, the method
"toString()" is called automatically, which returns a string to print.

Please provide your Fruit class first since you code is:

```
System.out.println(fruit);
```

If you didn't implement the toString() for class Fruit, address will be printed like:

```
Fruit@15db9742
```

Or, if you override toString() but didn't implement it carefully, problems will occur